# MediBang: Browse through multiple pages after selecting a page

Tags: applications, comics

In MediBang Paint Pro, how do open the next page that I created while starting a new project?

when I choose the `Draw Manga` option in the mini window that appears after opening MediBang, it lets me choose the number of pages.

[image: First] [image: Second]

**Then when I click on `OK`, it shows the list of pages.**

[image: Third]

But the problem is that after selecting one of the pages, I don't how to go to the next page. I can't find the option for it.

Thanks.

Comment: I've never even heard of this softwae.

Comment: And did you **read** that comment @user287001? (...and its really kind of creepy you searched for this). --- reposted here ---- The main issue with using some of the free image editors out there, is lack of community. You really are better off asking at the web site the product is from. I've never heard of "MediBang", which doesn't mean a great deal. But if the user base is small, you may not get any answers here.

Comment: Forgive that bad joke. I remove it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: top left corner of MediBang UI]

You can click the 7th icon ("open project dialog") on the toolbar to open "Manga Project" window from which you can navigate between pages.